# snprintf truncates the last sign

Tags: mysql, c, insert

Consider the following code:

```
char *myContent = "content";
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "INSERT INTO myTable (col1) VALUES('%s')",myContent);
char *query = malloc(size+2);
snprintf(query, size, "INSERT INTO myTable (col1) VALUES('%s')",myContent);
```

Now I have the problem that the last bracket is truncated:

```
(gdb) print query
$2 = 0x616080 "INSERT INTO myTable (col1) VALUES('content'"
```

This is not a valid SQL statement, so have you an idea what the reason could be that the last bracket is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`snprintf`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sprintf.3.html)returns:

> the number of characters printed (**not  including**  the trailing '\0' used to end output to strings)

But the size argument is:

> and vsnprintf() write at most size bytes (**including** the trailing null byte ('\0'))

So you should:

```
char *query = malloc(size+1);
snprintf(query, size+1, "INSERT INTO myTable (col1) VALUES('%s')",myContent);
```

Comment: ha.. i already tried char *query = malloc(size+1); but i forgot the +1 within the snprintf. thanks

Answer (score 0):

snprintf returns the size of the resulting string, not including the NULL terminator. I think you need to pass size+1 to the second snprintf.

Answer (score 0):

What the others have said. But as myContent hasn't changed, it's safe to simply say:

```
 sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO myTable (col1) VALUES('%s')",myContent);
```